# How to find the size of a file uploaded via Dropwizard REST API

Tags: jetty, multipartform-data, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard 0.7.0 to build an API for file upload. Ran into trouble validating the uploaded file size limit. I want to check the size before writing the file to disk

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response uploadFile(@Context final HttpServletRequest request, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart fileBodyPart) {

    /*
     * Check the request size
     */
    request.getPart("file").getSize();
.........
}
```

it throws an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2075) ~[jetty-  server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getPart(Request.java:2055) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
```

EDIT ----------------------

@David

Upgraded to dropwizard 0.8.0 however ran into another error

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FormDataBodyPart
org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart
org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition
```

Using these dependencies

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
 <artifactId>dropwizard-forms</artifactId>
 <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
 <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
 <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

added

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new MultiPartBundle());
```

and this too (after first failure)

```
env.jersey().register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being able to submit multipart data requires an additional dropwizard dependency. For 0.8 and higher the dependency is `dropwizard-forms`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-forms</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

http://www.dropwizard.io/0.8.0/docs/manual/forms.html

Example usage:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("myFileName") InputStream file,
        @FormDataParam("myFileName") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData
){

    long fileSize = fileMetaData.getSize();
    // etc
}
```

This is what I'm using. Perhaps upgrading is a solution for you.

If not, it is possible for dropwizard 0.7 but I haven't had to do it... From a quick google, it looks like you need the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

... and add the following to your applications `run` method:

```
environment.jersey().register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

Given the error "No multipart config for servlet" I'm assuming your upload doesn't work at all, without your size check?

Comment: I need to use the 0.7.0 version and the dependency is in place  
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>    

Even though the size check cannot be performed, I am able to upload a file.  

I also tried to set the multipart config element in a filter    

final MultipartConfigElement MULTI_PART_CONFIG = new MultipartConfigElement("", 102400,-1L,-1);  
ServletRequest.setAttribute(Request.__MULTIPART_CONFIG_ELEMENT, MULTI_PART_CONFIG);

Comment: Observed a couple of things  FormDataContentDisposition.getSize() return -1  Adding a filter with multipart config element produces an error  java.io.IOException: Missing content for multipart request
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.parse(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:494)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.getParts(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:402)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2083)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getPart(Request.java:2055)