# Missing dependency FormDataBodyPart, FileDataBodyPart, FormDataContentDisposition

Tags: jersey, multipart

I am trying to upload files via a dropwizard based API

Using Dropwizard 0.8.0 with

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
 <artifactId>dropwizard-forms</artifactId>
 <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
 <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
 <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

dependencies added for multipart support

when I run the project in Eclipse I get this error:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: Missing dependency org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart
SEVERE: Missing dependency org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition
```

Comment: Looks like you are mixing Jersey 1.x with Jersey 2.x.

Comment: There are no Jersey dependencies added explicitly except for the multipart

Comment: May I see your full `pom.xml`?

Comment: You are right. There is a dependency in `pom.xml` which itself has jersey 1.x as a dependency.

Comment: Which version do you want to use?

Comment: Its 0.7.0 .. however I ran into trouble with finding the uploaded file size using `request.getPart("file").getSize()` ..its just not working.. so tried using 0.8.0 as per suggestion received on my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836660/how-to-find-the-size-of-a-file-uploaded-via-dropwizard-rest-api)